# Creating an autocomplete textbox with checkboxlist using asp.net and jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

[as i shown in image i did autocomplete but i need checkboxlist associated with the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goSC5.png)i need an autocomplete textbox which will have a checkbox list associated with multiple selection option,

Answer (score 0):

Project.requestHandler.sendRequest(URL.INBOX_PAGE.GET_USERNAME_BY_USERID, userId, function (response)
{

if (response.d != null) {

$.each(response.d, function (key, value) {
$("#username").append($("").type("checkbox").val(value.Id).html(value.Name));

});

$("#username").uniform();
}

});

Comment: Replace this line in Above Code
$("#username").append($("<option></option>").type("checkbox").val(value.Id).html(value.Name));

Comment: i got solution similar to this in other way thank you

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
   var SelectedCheckboxes = []
   $('input:checkbox[name=chkbox]:checked').each(function() {
      SelectedCheckboxes.push($(this).val());
   })
   $(#textbox1).val(SelectedCheckboxes.join(','));
})
```

Comment: Firstly select all inputs which are checked from textbox then assign it to var array ,
push all values one by one and comma, then assign that var array to textbox value.

Comment: hi sir please review my issue once again

Comment: check with other answer given above